# How to use Laravel's 5.6 native Auth functionality with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-authentication

I am using the first-time laravel, and want to use the laravel Auth for login and registration, MongoDB as backend. Using this command enables the laravel Auth

```
    php artisan make:auth
```

will it work ? can anyone help me, how to do it..

Comment: [Check this article](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-can-use-mongo-db-in-laravel-54)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
php artisan make:auth
```

will just generate views since Laravel already comes with an Authentication feature so you don't have to build on scratch.

Now it is possible to have MongoDB as backend but it requires you to install a wrapper in order for Laravel to connect to your database.

I recommend using this [one](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb).

It requires PHP MongoDB extension to be installed in order for the package to fully work.